# Creating loops with xts

Tags: r, loops, xts

This may sound trivial, but I want to know how to create a loop with a xts objects. For example I have :

```
make<-rbind(mean(x['199901']),
        mean(x['199902']),
        mean(x['199903']),
        mean(x['199904']),
        mean(x['199905']),
        mean(x['199906']))
```

`x` is an xts object and I will like to extract monthly means from this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should use `period.apply`, here an example to compute the mean for each month

```
zoo.data <- xts(rnorm(31)+10,as.Date(13514:13744,origin="1970-01-01"))
ep <- endpoints(zoo.data,'months')
period.apply(zoo.data, INDEX=ep, FUN=function(x) mean(x))
```

So to get this for only the 6 first months :

```
period.apply(zoo.data, INDEX=ep[1:6], FUN=function(x) mean(x))
```

there are also some wrappers of this function, like:

```
apply.daily(x, FUN, ...)
apply.weekly(x, FUN, ...)
apply.monthly(x, FUN, ...)
apply.quarterly(x, FUN, ...)
apply.yearly(x, FUN, ...
```